# Execution time of ALTER COLUMN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, alter-table

Having a table with 60 columns, and 200 rows. Altering a `BIT` column from `NULL` to `NOT NULL`, now has a running execution time of over 3 hours. Why is this taking so long?

This is the query that I'm execution:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
ALTER COLUMN col BIT NOT NULL
```

Is there a faster way to do it, besides creating a new column, updating it with values from the old column, then dropping the old column and renaming the new one?

This is on MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IS the ALTER blocked by metadata shared locks held by other statements? Any ALTER requires a metadata exclusive lock, and as such will be block by any other statement that uses the table.

Check [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx), or look into [sys.dm_exec_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) and see who's blocking your ALTER INDEX.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that, and thought that SQL Server would throw an error in this case?

Comment: If you set the LOCK TIMEOUT it will throw a lock timeout error.

Answer (score 2):

Is it still running after 3 hours (while you post the question), or completes after 3 hours?

If it's still running run DBCC OPENTRAN: you've probably an open transaction somewhere that has left a schema lock on the table

Or `SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE blocked <> 0` gives you what has been blocked

Comment: Will DBCC OPENTRAN release the lock?

Comment: @Tommy Jakobsen: no. CLosing the connection/app/query window will

Comment: Well why should I run DBCC OPENTRAN then?