# Alter table column running very slow, unable to select data from that table now

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I ran a very simple alter table query

Alter table mytable alter column shortname nvarchar(35)

Tried increase the size of that column from 20 to 35 characters. After several minutes of that query still not completing, i canceled it. Now I'm unable to even do a select against that table. Normally select * takes less then a second to return results. Now after a few minutes it's still running with no results.

[Execution time of ALTER COLUMN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465455/execution-time-of-alter-column)

I looked at that thread but nothing in there provided any help for me.

The table itself has about 3000 records, mostly text, and most records amount to about a paragraph worth of text at most. As i said, doing a select * normally returns all records within a second.

This is SQL Server 2012

The column is one i added recently to the table. There are multiple FK relationships on this table, but none of them deal with this column.

Comment: You may have hit an edge case due to a corrupted table, no available disk, etc., I do this kind of stuff all the time with tables larger than yours without seeing behaviour like you describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `SELECT` is being blocked. A couple of potential things:

- the code could still be rolling back. When you hit cancel, if Management Studio hasn't yet shown you "Query canceled by user" or something along those lines, you'll need to keep waiting.
- the code could have been run in a transaction, and other queries are blocked by that. In the window where you ran this change (and clicked cancel), check for `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;` - if it is > 0, run `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;` that many times.

In either case, you should be able to check who or what is blocking your `SELECT`. Note the session ID that is running the query (this is the number like `59` or `71` that is in parentheses in the tab and/or status bar of your query window). Open a new query window (while that one continues to run) and run the following:

```
SELECT blocking_session_id, wait_type, last_wait_type
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = <value>;
-- replace <value> with the session id from the original query
```

Now, if `blocking_session_id` is a positive integer, you can see who or what *that* person is doing that is blocking you, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = <blocker>;

DBCC INPUTBUFFER(<blocker>);

-- replace <blocker> with the blocking_session_id
```

Otherwise, let us know what the `wait_type` value is...

Comment: Thanks - turns out i had another query running that was run as a transaction and it had not been committed or rolled back. I never realize that number on the tab was a session iD. I just assumed it was a tab number since it always starts at one when i open SSMS and goes up sequentially as I open tabs. Also, there's no wait_type_desc column, just wait_type